# Solution to prevent jsx from condensing white space

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, whitespace

Apparently, by default, jsx consolidates multiple whitespace characters into a single whitespace. I want to be able to preserve the true text, whitespaces and all, on render.

I have a solution, but I'm not very pleased with it, and hoping someone has a more elegant solution.

Here's what I have so far.

```
((text)=>

(<span>
  {(text =>
  text
  .split('')
  .map(c =>
  c.charCodeAt(0) == 32 ? <span>&nbsp;</span> : <span>{c}</span>
  )
  )(text)}
</span>)

)('This has lots of whitespace ')
```

Also, does anyone know why they chose to add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the style `whitespace: pre-wrap`

[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/whitespace-condensing-issue-fix-q7qlq?file=/src/App.js)

```js
<p style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>This has lots of whitespace </p>}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a better solution. Thank You!